# timeout/memory leak with Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm writing an app using Cordova/Phonegap 2.2.0

Its running on an LG Ally (Android 2.2.2)

The app retrieves a rather large amount of data from a web server and in the process the app prematurely ends.  I say that instead of errors out because I don't get the typical Android "Application stopped responding" dialog.  Instead, the app exits and and returns to the home screen.

The log shows the following message:

```
D/DroidGap(4018): Paused the application!
D/CordovaWebView(4018): Handle the pause
W/dalvikvm(4018): ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)
W/dalvikvm(4018): Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table:
W/dalvikvm(4018):   502: 0x44ae70c8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   503: 0x44c93538 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   504: 0x44c76b70 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   505: 0x44a64810 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   506: 0x449ef708 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   507: 0x449d06b8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   508: 0x449cd330 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   509: 0x449cc198 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   510: 0x449cb4c8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018):   511: 0x449ea780 cls=Landroid/webkit/WebViewCore; (132 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(4018): JNI local reference table summary (512 entries):
W/dalvikvm(4018):   496 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (496 unique)
W/dalvikvm(4018):    15 of Ljava/lang/String; 36B (15 unique)
W/dalvikvm(4018):     1 of Landroid/webkit/WebViewCore; 132B
W/dalvikvm(4018): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 14560 bytes
E/dalvikvm(4018): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
I/dalvikvm(4018): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=8 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(4018):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x449ea828 self=0x1274c8
I/dalvikvm(4018):   | sysTid=4025 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1221400
I/dalvikvm(4018):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeHandleTouchEvent(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(4018):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3400(WebViewCore.java:52)
I/dalvikvm(4018):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1159)
I/dalvikvm(4018):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/dalvikvm(4018):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
I/dalvikvm(4018):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:623)
I/dalvikvm(4018):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
E/dalvikvm(4018): VM aborting
```

I'm unsure if this is a timeout problem or if I'm running the device out of memory or what's going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution to this error. Move your resources (images, fonts,..) from your asset forlder to sdcard folder and te error is fixed !